# What do the $xx$ symbols in front of the encripted strings mean?

Tags: php, content-management-system, cryptography

I've noticed that lots of PHP software, such as Joomla! or Wordpress prepend "$xx$." symbols to their hashed strings. This happens, for example, when storing user passwords in databases.
What's the reason for this?

Comment: It denotes the hashing algorithm used.

Comment: It identifies the particular hashing algorithm used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$xx$` denotes what hashing algorithm is used. One reason why it is useful that this is part of the resulting string, is that it allows you to have multiple types of hashes in the database without things breaking because you don't know what hashing algorithm was used. It also gives you an upgrade-path, to increase security of your passwords.

If you use `crypt`, you just use `crypt($password, $hash) == $hash` and `crypt` figures out from the hash you provide which algorithm to use. It can also extract the salt, and other options (depending on the algorithm).

For example for sha256, you get something like "`$5$rounds=5000$usesomesillystri$KqJWpanXZHKq2BOB43TSaYhEWsQ1Lr5QNyPCDH/Tp.6`" (from http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php ). The "`5`" denotes the hashing algorithm, the "`rounds=5000`" is an option the hashing algorithm uses, and "`usesomesillystringforsalt`" is a salt, which insures that hashes of the same password looks different for different people, and making it harder to brute-force attack the hash. The "`KqJWpanXZHKq2BOB43TSaYhEWsQ1Lr5QNyPCDH/Tp.6`" is the actual hashed password.

Comment: NOte that if it actually reads `"usesomesillystringforsalt"` then the implementer made a mistake, salt should be generated by a secure random number generator, otherwise attacks may apply.